# Passing parameters in Silverlight URL

Tags: silverlight, ria, silverlight-5.0

I have developed a Silverlight RIA Application. Assume the site link is `http://MySilverlightApp`
In my main.xaml page I navigate to a different view (e.g Page1). So when I go to `http://MySilverlightApp` I get routed to `http://MySilverlightApp/#/Page1`

In this Page1.xaml I display a list of radio buttons. Each radio button has an ID and upon selecting a radio button I display further things on the page.

I want to pass that ID from url itself, like `http://MySilverlightApp/#/Page1?ID=13`

Then when my page loads I can grab that ID and select the radio button (with ID 13) and display the material right there.

How can I accomplish this ? I want to grab the string not in code behind but in Page1 view model. (not binding, just want to retrieve value)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I did.

In my code behind I introduced a property to query and find out if any parameters are passed or not.

```
private string ParamValue
        {
            get
            {
                string paramValue = "";
                const string paramName = "ID";

                if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey(paramName))
                    paramValue = NavigationContext.QueryString[paramName];

                return paramValue;
            }
        }
```

In my Loaded Event handler I invoke the view model's public method and pass in the ID.
Something like

```
private void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ParamValue))
            {
                Page1iewModel page1ViewModel = this.DataContext as Page1ViewModel ;
                page1ViewModel.SetID(ParamValue);
            }
        }
```